# Get array from file which also includes strings

Tags: python, json

I'm writing an automation script in Python that makes use of another library. The output I'm given contains the array I need, however the output also includes log messages in string format that are irrelevant.

For my script to work, I need to retrieve only the array which is in the file.

Here's an example of the output I'm getting.

```
Split /adclix.$~image into 2 rules
Split /mediahosting.engine$document,script into 2 rules
[
    {
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        }, 
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "/adservice\\.", 
            "unless-domain": [
                "adservice.io"
            ]
        }
    }
]
Generated a total of 1 rules (1 blocks, 0 exceptions)
```

How would I get only the array from this file?

FWIW, I'd rather not have the logic based on the strings outside of the array, as they could be subject to change.

UPDATE: Script I'm getting the data from is here: https://github.com/brave/ab2cb/tree/master/ab2cb

My full code is here:

```
def pipe_in(process, filter_lists):
try:
    for body, _, _ in filter_lists:
        process.stdin.write(body)
finally:
    process.stdin.close()    


def write_block_lists(filter_lists, path, expires):

block_list = generate_metadata(filter_lists, expires)
process = subprocess.Popen(('ab2cb'),
                           cwd=ab2cb_dirpath,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
threading.Thread(target=pipe_in, args=(process, filter_lists)).start()

result = process.stdout.read()
with open('output.json', 'w') as destination_file:
    destination_file.write(result)
    destination_file.close()
if process.wait():
    raise Exception('ab2cb returned %s' % process.returncode)
```

The output will ideally be modified in stdout and written later to file as I still need to modify the data within the previously mentioned array.

Comment: Can you share the Python script you're running to get that output

Comment: There are two arrays. Do you mean the "unless-domain" member? How do you propose to locate it if not by this identifier?

Comment: @tripleee the main array which encloses everything other than the `split` and `generated` strings.

Comment: You already seem to have solved that, and we can't see the data that this was extracted from. Whatever printed that message has already extracted this information. Just examine the code which prints this message.

Comment: @tripleee I've updated the post with my code and a link to the original library. As I'm making use of stdin & stdout, I'm not sure of a possibility to remove log files using the options on the original library.

Comment: This code? https://github.com/bnomis/ab2cb It has an option to output the rules to a file; use that.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but outputting the rules to a file isn't what I asked for. The accepted answer allows me to manipulate the data without having to save data to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex too

```
import re

input = """
Split /adclix.$~image into 2 rules
Split /mediahosting.engine$document,script into 2 rules
[
    {
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        }, 
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "/adservice\\.", 
            "unless-domain": [
                "adservice.io"
            ]
        }
    }
]
Generated a total of 1 rules (1 blocks, 0 exceptions)
asd
asd
"""

regex = re.compile(r"\[(.|\n)*(?:^\]$)", re.M)
x = re.search(regex, input)
print(x.group(0))
```

**EDIT**

*re.M* turns on 'MultiLine matching'

https://repl.it/repls/InfantileDopeyLink

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library for this purpose. It's not often that I get to plug it!

```
from jsonfinder import jsonfinder

logs = r"""
Split /adclix.$~image into 2 rules
Split /mediahosting.engine$document,script into 2 rules
[
    {
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        }, 
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "/adservice\\.", 
            "unless-domain": [
                "adservice.io"
            ]
        }
    }
]
Generated a total of 1 rules (1 blocks, 0 exceptions)
Something else that looks like JSON: [1, 2]
"""

for start, end, obj in jsonfinder(logs):
  if (
      obj 
      and isinstance(obj, list)
      and isinstance(obj[0], dict)
      and {"action", "trigger"} <= obj[0].keys()
  ):
    print(obj)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/ImperfectJuniorBootstrapping

Library: https://github.com/alexmojaki/jsonfinder

Install with `pip install jsonfinder`.